# How to make this wispy rocking swinging smoke?

Tags: animation

This is my first question on this forum and my first time with Blender.

(I had asked) Is it possible to make this kind of rocking swinging smoke-wisp action in Blender?
There's a link to what I'm referring to here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ge3iC7TJgQOmcBKOIMbxntYx9YD9W0F1/view

Many video's of this process on YouTube are outdated, or on older versions (older than 3.0 and therefore don't work in new versions of Blender), and although they seem to show explosions and comets, missiles and the like, very few show a wisp of smoke weaving, winding, dodging and swinging along on an uncertain horizontal path the way I need it to -

I see the answers say 'Yes', so the NEXT QUESTION is - is there a quick way to learn this skill, the settings? If so, perhaps a link to a clip or a tutor?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

well...it would have been good if you have showed us what you tried so far instead of just giving a link to a complex smoke simulation. So it seems to me more like "please do the work for me, i am too lazy to watch endless tutorials".

So i will answer a bit like your question, very vague, very common.

1. of course this is possible
2. simulations like gas + fire + water are pretty complex

So whenever you change one parameter, the whole simulation could look like shit because of that.
The interrelations are quite complex.

So i made this fire + smoke simulation with fire, so that you can see better the colors and whats going on and because i was too lazy to make good smoke materials.

[image]

the most important parameters are:

- move/animate your inflow
- animate your "use inflow" (turn it on and off multiple times)
- use high resolution
- use dissolve
- use noise
- use initial velocity

you should invest time in watching good yt tutorials to make really great looking smoke. Yes, this takes days and weeks. Practice with smoke as much as you can. As quicker you will get a feeling how it works and what the parameters will do.

Comment: I can only agree that this question is a bit too vague... one cannot simply answer "yes, set this parameter and it works". As @Chris says, I would also suggest watch YT tutorials on this subject (the more, the better). I can only speak for myself, but I've watched different tutorials and tutors do lots of things differently, so I learn by watching them **and** playing around to find my own best way to do it.

Comment: yep, i totally agree with that. Play around, practice yourself. YT tutorials give you a guide...but if you just put in the parameters to rebuild - it won't help you in long term.

Comment: Yeah, Chris, that's EXACTLY what I need to learn to do - I see now it can be done, the task is to learn to do it asap. Wondering, how long does it take to make that if you know what you're doing? Are there any clips around that show that, which you just did, anywhere?

Comment: just search in google for "blender smoke simulation tutorial". A very good teacher is in my opinion polyfjord.

Comment: how long does it take...well...that depends on many things. How much time to you have? 8h/day? 2h/day? 16h/day? How quick do you learn/understand? what is your knowledge right now? about Blender? about Smoke? and so on....if you know what you are doing and if you are an expert you can do this in 10 mins. If you have no experience at all and you are a bloody beginner in Blender...it might take 6 weeks or longer to do it.